# JQueryUI dragging a div that contains an image

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm having a weird problem.
I'm using JQueryUI to drag around divs that contain an  tag. 
When those divs are stationary, the img is perfectly centered in the div (how I want it to be) but when I'm dragging it, the image is not centered anymore but all the way to the left of the div.
Mind, I'm dragging a helper that I add to the body of my html.
If I DON'T add it to the body, I don't have that problem but I don't get at all why it's not working if I do.
My body does not have css that should change the layout so I'm kind of confused.
Here is my CSS for the parent div:

```
.draggable-stream{
vertical-align: top;
background-color: white;
display: inline-block;
height: 9vh;
width: 9vh;
margin-left: 4%;
margin-top: .5vh;
border-radius: 50%;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #555;
}
```

And for the contained image:

```
.draggable-img{
margin-top: 14%;
height: 6vh;
width: 6vh;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

When I inspect the elements with Firebug I can see that there is no margin etc added to the helper element while dragging, it has exactly the same values as the stationary one.
On top of that, if I give the .draggable-img a margin, it works on both the helper and the stationary element, but as the stationary element - image was already centered, it gets moved out of center, while the helper gets centered.

Oh, I'm using Bootstrap and JQueryUI css, but again, according to Firebug, those styles aren't messing with my own.

Comment: can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) recreating the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the draggable should have position as absolute. Its must.

Try this in the draggable class. Juzz add this.

`position:absolute;`

This will solve it.

```
.draggable-img{ 
         position: absolute;
         margin-top: 14%; 
         height: 6vh; 
         width: 6vh; 
         margin-bottom: 0; 
  }
```

Comment: Dont add it to the draggable container, just add it to the draggable inside the container. Actually actually jquery-ui draggable demo page they used the class for draggable ad draagable-ui-item somewhat like that, but they dont show it. But inside that theyve declared it with `position:absolute`

Comment: Thanks, that solved it, although I had to add it to the class that was used WHILE dragging, so I just added another class draggable-img-dragging when the div was dragged and had it set to position:absolute!